# How to get user object of currently logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

What is the correct way to get an Identity User Object (from the identity framework) of the currently logged in user in a controller?

I need to update some properties against the user (table AspNetUsers) and do not know the correct method of getting the user object so that I could do things such as:

```
  var menuItem = context.MenuItems.First(m => m.Description == "New Order");
  var user = ??????????
  user.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

I've slightly modified the original user model by adding a few properties and renaming the class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I retrieve this `User` object from my controllers?

Answer (score 3):

In the controller class use the namespace *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity* and the get the current user like this:

```
var user = User.Identity;
```

Example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
...
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = User.Identity;
        ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Getting Profile Information:
[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) gives the steps to add profile information to your user.

To retrieve your user data you should:

1. Get the current logged in UserId, so you can look the user up in
   ASP.NET Identity system

> var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

2. Instantiate the UserManager in ASP.Identity system so you can look
   up the user in the system

> var manager = new UserManager(new UserStore(new MyDbContext()));

3. Get the User object

> var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

4. Get the profile information about the user

> currentUser.MyUserInfo.FirstName

Comment: Thankyou. I've added additional properties to my user (see my edit). How do I access these?

Comment: @Lock Check my edited answer. I think this link should help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Get username**

```
var userName = User.Identity.Name;

Get the user using static method created below.

var user = GetCurrentUser(userName);
```

**Static method to get user**

```
            public static User GetCurrentUser(string userName)
            {
                var userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new YourIdentityDbContext()));
                var user = userManager.FindByName(userName);
                return user;
            }
```